# Should I capitalize the second element in a hyphenated word if the first is a number?

Tags: capitalization, hyphenation

I am adding a contest I attended to my CV. The official name (translated into English from another language) is '3-minute Physics' popular science competition. However, if I want to make my CV read more formal, should I capitalize 'minute' in the hyphenated word, given the first element is a number? From the rules I found online:

> 1.Always capitalize the first element.
> 2.Capitalize any subsequent elements unless they are articles, prepositions, coordinating conjunctions

Is it appropriate for me to capitalize 'M' ? Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to answer this other than with personal opinion, since capitalisation in such cases is a matter of *style*. Have you thought to consult a relevant style guide? Also, I'd have thought a more relevant (but still opinion-based) question is whether to replace the number "3" with the word "Three". FWIW, I'd render this as "Three-Minute Physics". See also [APA Style Guide – Title Case](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/capitalization/title-case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Formatting of a CV or resume is not universal; there aren't hard and fast "rules."
2. Note, the reason you are interested in capitalization here is because you're dealing with a proper noun. (The competition has an official name and you're using it.) It's up to you, but I would probably not format every entry in a CV or resume using title case (like "I Saved the Company $20,000 in the First Quarter").
3. Even the question of whether to capitalize within hyphenated phrases might have different answers from one style guide to another. It looks like the *Chicago Manual of Style* [just simplified its position](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2010/08/capitalizing-hyphenated-words-in-titles.html) in the 2020 edition, in fact, at least as regards hyphenated words in titles, to say "Sure, just capitalize all words in a hyphenated phrase."
4. It's usually preferable, in formal writing, to spell out small numbers instead of using numerals. (Different style guides have different cutoffs below which you would use numerals) For instance, "Three-Minute Physics," but "20,000 Leagues Under the Sea."
5. But note, proper nouns sometimes have their own preference for how they're styled. A certain energy drink seems to consistently style itself as "5-hour ENERGY"—numeral, hyphen, lower case "hour," all-caps "energy." But, as with "the artist [usually] known as Prince," entities that make requirements about their stylization often run afoul of tradition or style guides; it's easy to find "5-Hour Energy" and "Five-Hour Energy." Since in this case you're translating (and perhaps also transliterating from another alphabet?), I would guess that "Three-Minute Physics" is unobjectionable.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks so much :)